# oracle sql to db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, zos, db2-zos

I have to change an Oracle SQL DDL to use it in zOS/DB2. Now I'm stuck in this part:

```
 ... ATTRIBUTE1 char check (IS_FINISHED in (0,1)),
     ATTRIBUTE2 char check (HAS_ERROR in (0,1)),...
```

I have never used a 'check' in oracle, neither in DB2.
Can someone please help me out here? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are inline check constraints.  Normally, the column names and  types would match.  In either database, I would expect:

```
 IS_FINISHED char(1) check (IS_FINISHED in ('0', '1')),
 HAS_ERROR char(1) check (HAS_ERROR in ('0', '1')),
```

If inline `check` constraints are not allowed in a database, then you can add them as you would other constraints:

```
alter table t
    add constraint chk_t_is_finished check (IS_FINISHED in ('0', '1'),
    add constraint chk_t_has_error check (HAS_ERROR in ('0', '1');
```